# Descobrir vencedor Jogo Galo / Jogo Velha

Tags: c

Estou a desenvolver o jogo do galo / jogo da velha e nesse jogo tenho que verificar a cada nova jogada ou iteração se existe algum vencedor. Comecei por tentar fazer isto para uma matriz estática predefinida por mim e comecei também por fazer a verificação primeiramente excluindo das duas diagonais possíveis. O código é o seguinte

**UPDATE**

```
int main()
{

int VEC[3][3] = {
                {1,1,1},
                {0,1,0},
                {1,0,1}
              };
int m = 3;
int n = 3;
int i = 0,j = 0,count = 1,total = 0;

for(i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    for(j = 0; j < 3; j++)
    {
        if(VEC[i][j] == VEC[i][j+1])
        {
            count++;
            if(count == 3)
            {
                printf("GANHOU!\n");
                break;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            count = 0;
            break;
        }
    }
    }
}
```

Neste caso que apresentei ele diz-me que existe um vencedor e realmente está ali uma chave vencedora na última linha da matriz. Mas eu tenho algumas dúvidas em relação a este código. Primeiramente porque eu penso que em todas as linhas eu saiu fora da matriz por estar a verificar a posição j + 1. E não sei até que ponto isso é bastante errado ou não. Depois tentei controlar essa situação adicionando i <= 3 e j <= 3 mas eu necessito sempre de verificar se a posição seguinte á que estou é igual para aumentar a contagem de valores iguais para saber se encontrei 3 valores que dão a chave vencedora.

**INFORMAÇÃO NOVA**

Já consegui colocar a encontrar a chave vencedora mas se existirem 2 chaves ele dá-me 2 vencedores. Como posso fazer para terminar o programa quando a condição de vencedor é encontrada? Terminar na totalidade uma vez que apenas 1 jogador pode vencer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você precisa verificar se há um vencedor para os dois jogadores. Recomendo utilizar funções e então varrer a matriz. Ex: a primeira função verifica se a linha de cima esta preenchida com apenas "x", no caso jogador um, se sim, retorna o ganhador se não continua o jogo. Se estiver com dúvida ainda. Posso fazer o código, mas seria melhor que você tentasse.

Comment: Essa parte terei que fazer ainda mas tenho uma ideia como fazer, mas entretanto penso que consegui colocar a descobrir o vencedor de forma correta mas precisava de quebrar todos os ciclos quando encontrasse o vencedor. Neste momento ele mesmo que ache o vencedor na primeira linha da matriz continua a percorrer a matriz quando eu pretendia que parasse porque apenas podemos ter um vencedor no jogo. Alguma dica? Pensei que o "break" resultasse mas pelos vistos não!

Comment: Faz uma função que contenha um retorno 1 ou 0. 1 sendo o jogador e 0 o segundo jogador. Recebe na main esse valor faz as condições e coloca um break dentro do laço. Darei um dica de como eu fiz.. Criei um do while e chamei as funções dentro passando a matriz como parâmetro. Caso haja um vencedor ele para o laço. Caso seja empate ele zera a matriz e inicia um novo jogo. Fiz o mais simples possível